# Beginner to October CMS plugin development

Tags: octobercms

I am looking to develop a few bespoke plugins for the laravel based October CMS for a client.

I have read through a good portion of the documentation (but not all of it) and I cannot find any information for the following:

- Plugins with their own tables and database migrations
- Adding custom plugin page and functionality to the admin area

It has been a long day and i may have just missed the topics on this area in the documentation but if anyone happens to have good knowledge or better, example code, that would be great

Comment: Asking for tutorial and off-site resources is off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: October does have a Support section with many tutorials and links to get you started, e.g. http://octobercms.com/support/article/ob-18

Comment: it does and it also states: "Great! If your question is about programming or development try Stack Overflow for an answer, using the octobercms tag."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All about making plugins for October CMS: http://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/registration#introduction

It's about database migrations (plugin's own tables) and adding settings pages, menu items, lists and forms to the backend admin interface.

Answer (score 0):

Look at builder plugin. It's a good start to plugin development and understand plugin structure and scaffolding.